# Getting actual content from RSS feed

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, rss, windows-store-apps

Here for example there is a link for ABC news which gives various RSS feeds to consume.

http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss`

Using this feeds in Windows 8 store app, I am able to read it using built in SyndicationClient class. However, it gives only title and few summary text for the news story/article and not all content. Now I want to have all content i.e. Text and Image. I saw many news reader app for Windows store and they are doing it pretty much easily when I tap on any story and it gives me actual content right there.

Any idea how to accomplish this? Do I need some sort of html parser here?

You can have a look at News, News Bento app for example. I want to achieve something similar.

Here are the images from the app:

This is extracted text and images from the news article:

[image]
This is the view when you click on "View Original Article". I know that view below is using webview control. But I want how to extract data like image above.
[image]

Comment: My guess is that those apps are not showing you the summarized feed data, but they are actually opening up the web site article using a browser control.

Comment: No. They are showing text and image content from the actual news article on the website. I will post screenshot right here in few mins.

Comment: That image does not match with the cnn feed. Also, the second image is showing you a `WebView` displaying the entire PopCrush website.

Comment: Yes. It doesn't match and it need not to. I have written that it has extracted texts. See article content is same. Also I know other image is of webview. I have written that in question itself. What I want is how to get that html from RSS feed and display in WinRT control like richtextblock.

Comment: I have given cnn feed for example. And screenshot is for different feed. If you have Windows 8, you can try free News Bento app to see what I mean.

Comment: @JayNanavaty How about posting a concrete question like *"I have this rss feed and I want to extract that data"* ?

Comment: @L.B I actually need to deal with any valid RSS feed which can be parsed by SyndicationClient class in Windows 8 store app framework. Anyway, it seems people are having hard time to understand what I am asking, I will either modify this question or close and open new one with more detail and example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, answer is readablity. More here as well:

https://github.com/scottksmith95/CSharp.Readability

It took me lot of time to find out this stuff but it is exactly what I wanted.